# d3 axis date ticks on brush/zoom

Tags: d3.js

I've been able to use the great tutorial for brush/zoom:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

I'm using the following scales and axis variables:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeDay).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%x"));
var xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2).ticks(10).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%x"));
```

Looks OK when zoomed in:
[image]

However, it gets extremely packed when zooming out:
[image]

How can I set the max number of tick marks, but limit the most granular tick to a single day?